# Excel formula round up after number (30) instead of 50 to nearest hundred

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I think the title says it all, is it possible to round up after a number (30 in this case) to the nearest hundred? I believe the ROUND function rounds after 50 by default. I'm looking for an Excel formula that can do this.

Sorry I should have provided some example.

Consider the following numbers (it will always be whole numbers):

```
Given   Expected
120     100
130     200
131     200
5410    5400
5430    5500
```

Comment: So, 1.29 becomes 1, 1.3 becomes 2, ..., 1.99 becomes 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this.

It checks if the last two numbers in the WHOLE number (I assume you don't have digits) is equal to 30 or larger. If that's the case it will round up to nearest 100. Otherwise it will round down to nearest 100.

```
=IF(VALUE(RIGHT(A1,2))>=30,ROUNDUP(A1,-2),ROUNDDOWN(A1,-2))
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
=IF(A3-INT(A3)<0.3,INT(A3),INT(A3)+1)
```

EDIT:

This is only the  direction in which you might be going. It refers to positive whole numbers. But it needs a lot of work e.g. when i changed the factor to 2 in one case dblDif ended up being 1.9999999999 instead of 2. So use this only as an idea:

```
Function R30(Num As Double, Round As Integer, Optional Factor As Integer) _
    As Double

  If IsMissing(Factor) Then Factor = 3

  Dim dblNum As Double
  Dim dblDif As Double

  dblNum = Num / 10 ^ Round
  dblDif = (dblNum - Int(dblNum)) * 10 ^ Round

  If dblDif <> 0 Then
    If dblDif < Factor * 10 ^ (Round - 1) Then
      R30 = Int(dblNum) * 10 ^ Round
     Else
      R30 = (Int(dblNum) + 1) * 10 ^ Round
    End If
   Else
    R30 = Num
  End If

End Function

Sub R30use()
  Debug.Print R30(133, 1, 3)
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't have the expected results

Comment: I know, the matter is far more complicated. I will upload a function for whole numbers shortly.

Answer (score 2):

For the sample now provided:

```
=IF(1*RIGHT(A1,2)<30,A1-RIGHT(A1,2),A1+100-RIGHT(A1,2))
```

Comment: This is what I thought after reading the text. But the comment below changed the whole thing.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't have the expected results

Answer (score 0):

I have written this custom function which also takes into account numbers below 0.

```
Function CustomRound(lngValue As Long)
    Dim lngValueMin   As Long
    Dim lngValuePart  As Long
    Dim intNeg        As Integer

    If lngValue < 0 Then
        lngValue = lngValue * -1
        intNeg = -1
    Else
        intNeg = 1
    End If

    lngValueMin = lngValue - Right(lngValue, 2)
    lngValuePart = Right(lngValue, 2)

    If lngValuePart < 30 Then
      CustomRound = lngValueMin * intNeg
    Else
      CustomRound = (lngValue + (100 - lngValuePart)) * intNeg
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: In my function attempt was trying to round everything, e.g. 0.3 to 1, 3 to 10, 30 to 100 etc., sorry.

Comment: @VBasic2008 No worries I appreciate your input